# Ant is unable to find a javac compiler

Tags: java, linux, ant

I am trying to build some binaries of an application. When i am trying to make the build, I am getting this:

`BUILD FAILED
/home/.../ant-build.xml:84: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"`

The application requires java 7, and i have it installed but i had it along java 8. The build requires for tools.jar which is located in java 7 only, therefore after several attempts i uninstalled java 8. However, when I am trying make again, i get the same error, even though i don't have java8 installed at all!

I set the JAVA_HOME properly:

`$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`

I doubt i need the path but i set that one up just in case as well :

`$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin`

I'm running out of ideas here :P any help would be appreciated.

*Also something maybe important, I had to add the repo manually to get java-7 otherwise it wasnt able to locate the package. Thats when i got double jdk-s.*

Comment: So the problem is that your build complains about an old value of  $JAVA_HOME that points to JRE8 instead of your updated value for JDK7?

Comment: Im not sure, it feels like that but since it has been totally deleted i guess that it should change. It also states in the beginning this 
`Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar` .

Comment: try setting it inside you ~/.bashrc or in /etc/bash.bashrc and then source ~/.bashrc or source /etc/bash.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are calling the JAVAC command from any other source/tool like Jenkins/Bamboo/Teamcity. Make sure you have set the environment variable of that tool. usually it lies in the manage tool option.

I was facing same issue while using Jenkins.If you don't set up an environment variable in tool from which you are making a call it take your 
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre" so go and set the the env variable JAVA_HOME of you tools. attaching screen shot of Jenkins issue. Go to Manage Jenkins -->configure system --> environment variables and set you java_home path.
Cheers[image: issue]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same situation.

That is because `JAVA_HOME` is not correctly set in `sudo` environment.

I added `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to` in `/root/.bashrc`, and eventually it was built right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using `javac` of java8 with `JAVA_HOME` or `CLASS_PATH` pointing to java7.

You can use `which java` to check that.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export export ${PATH}=${JAVA_HOME}:/bin:${PATH}`
```